# Deleting model and its related model returns status code 404, but its deleted

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-9

I have a job called `DeletePost.php` which performs the delete action, the post model has two related models. After performing `dispatchSync` to run the job, all the model and related model were deleted correctly, but it returns `404`.

The only exception I can get from `debugbar` is that. and only one request being made.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**`web.php`**

```
Route::delete('/user/profile/post/delete/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])
  ->where('postId', '[0-9]+')
  ->name('account.post.destroy');
```

**`App/http/controller/PostController.php`**

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize(PostPolicy::DELETE, $post);

        $this->dispatchSync(new DeletePost($post));

        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', ['Successful !', 'Post deleted successfully']);
    }
```

**App/Job/DeletePost**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class DeletePost implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(private readonly Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle() :void
    {
        $this->post->delete();
    }
}
```

> Note that I have overwritten the `delete` method in my `post` model.

**`App/model/Post.php`**

```
public function delete(){
    $this->removePostPhotos();

    parent::delete();
}

public function removePostPhotos()
{
    $this->postPhotosRelation()->delete();

    $this->unsetRelation('postPhotosRelation');
}
```

**`Forntend`**

```
deletePost() {
            Inertia.delete(route("account.post.destroy", [this.post.id]), {
                method: "DELETE",
                preserveScroll: true,
            });
        },
```

Comment: If the post is deleted the 404 might be coming from the dashboard route

Comment: @apokryfos what do you mean?

Comment: the part `return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with('success', ['Successful !', 'Post deleted successfully']);` might be the cause of the 404 error

Comment: @apokryfos, But why?  route('dashboard') is accessible

Comment: @apokryfos, even removing return redirect to somewhere, it still returns 404

Comment: Seems you are using ajax to request Post deletion. If so please check whether there's another ajax call being made (i.e. second immediately after the first one which executes successfully) by mistake in your js code - check if instead of single request there are two requests to the delete route via ajax

Comment: @Donkarnash, I am using the Inertia `delete` method to send the delete request, in the admin panel I can only see one request being made so that prob not the problem.

Comment: @JamesWOng if you're using ajax then the redirect won't work. Inertia might try to sync the model state after the request which would result in the 404 since the model would be deleted at that point.

Comment: @apokryfos, I see. What should i do instead ?

Comment: The most basic solution would be to put a normal form in your view e.g. `<form action="{{ route('account.post.destroy', [ 'postId' => $post->id ]) }}" method="POST">@method('DELETE')<button>Delete</button></form>` this should make a normal request a do a full page reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@apokryfos has pointed out the problem after you submit a `delete` request to the server, the server delete the post first then response that's why I am getting `404`

I have figured out a solution where you respond first and then dispatch the jobs.

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize(PostPolicy::DELETE, $post);

        DeletePost::dispatchAfterResponse($post);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', ['Successful !', 'Post deleted successfully']);
    }
```

> use the `dispatchAfterResponse` method when you dispatch the job.